# Dropbox API with WebAuthenticationBroker

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-8, dropbox-api

I am using  WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync() method. 
After successfully logging in and granting access to my application, it stays at the Dropbox success screen and does not redirect to my local metro application. I have to click back to app and then metro app detects that as user canceled.

Also, what should be the callback URL value ? As of now I am keeping it blank as it is a metro app & it seems to be working fine.

Am i missing something ?

Comment: Can you please post some code so someone can try it out for you?

Comment: I have checked Web authentication broker sample(http://goo.gl/5m5Y3) , but it seems to be broken or i am doing something wrong.
 I tested it with scenario 2 (twitter, as it also uses OAuth 1.0) In this sample as well as my code, i get stuck as same point. Even after user grants permission to app, the WebBroker UI never dismisses. Check the screenshot. It stays as it is. http://imgur.com/5Eaps
I was expecting that WebBroker should return me the response object once the user grants permission. 
PS : callback URL was supplied as http://www.google.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: This was because i used URL as string directly instead of using Uri.EscapeDataString() method

Comment: Would you please elaborate your answer a bit? I'm facing exactly the issue that you had in the past. Thank you!